# Express with Stylus and static CSS

Tags: node.js, express, stylus

I'm using Node.Js with Express 3 and Stylus.

My app.js: https://gist.github.com/luizhrqas/6642307

But i want to use some static CSS (like bootstrap.min.css) and some stylus CSS (for example, appliction.styl).

But if i put on my view: 
`link(type='text/css', rel='stylesheet', href='/css/boostrap.min.css')`

The browser returns: Cannot GET /css/boostrap.min.css

I think that the Stylus Middleware is trying to find '/css/bootstrap.min.styl'

How i can do to the Stylues Middleware import static CSS and stylus CSS at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this changing the src parameter of Stylus Middlware to src: __dirname + '/public', and creating an application.styl, and inside this application.styl, using @import "bootstrap.min.css"

Thanks!